# square bracket content coding

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I want to apply a style in ms-word to all the square brackets with only number/numbers(numbers separated with comma or dash/hyphen and space) in them.

Eg:  [1 ] , [1 , 2] [1,2,3], [1, 2, 3], [1-3],[1 , 2]

[image]

The reason I have to apply regex in this case is because, in each case as shown in the attached image, numbers may come in different formats inside the square brackets. Such as single digits, digits with/without space after/before comma, hyphen/endash in between digits etc.

Comment: I think there are options there. Do you really need to use Regex? I don't think so

Comment: @AminahNuraini: I have edited the question for your convenience. Please check

Comment: You have added VBA tags, are you using the real regex, not the search and replace dialog? If yes, use a simple [`\[\d+([-,]+\d+)*\]`](https://regex101.com/r/hY4vL3/1).

Answer (score 1):

Bring up the `Find and Replace` box and enter the following in the `Find what:` textbox:

```
\[[0-9, -]@\]
```

The click the `More >>` button and ensure that `Use wildcards` checkbox is checked.

You may use the `Replace with:` textbox to replace these with whatever text or formatting you want to.

[image: Find and Replace with Wildcard]

**NOTE:** If you are looking for a VBA solution only, the easiest way is to record a macro while performing the above steps, and then customize it according to your needs.

Comment: It will also match `[-------]` and `[     ]`, and `[--,--,]`, and `[-, -,]`, etc.

Comment: Yes, but that's assuming that this is a sensible document and has real text.

Comment: Good, but the question is tagged VBA.

Comment: That's probably because the OP thinks that there is no built-in way to to search for these type of text. Anyways, its good if someone posts a VBA solution and he prefers that one. :)